# CakePHP - Change the "for" attribute of a label

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to make a checkbox, with a label before it that is not attached to the input, and a label after the checkbox that controls the actual input.  It should look like this on the page:

```
Account Suspended:  [X] Prevent the user from logging in
```

**view.ctp**

```
$this->Form->label('Account Suspended');
$this->Form->input('account_suspended', array(
    'type' => 'checkbox',
    'label' => 'Prevent the user from logging in'
));
```

The problem I am having at the moment is that the first label is being created with an automatically generated `for` attribute that matches the ID of the input, so both labels toggle the checkbox if you click them.

The CakePHP generated markup for the first label looks like this, because it is automatically converting the label value into a camel-case ID for the `for` attribute:

```
<label for="CustomerAccountSuspended">Account Suspended:</label>
```

I want the first label to just be:

```
<label>Account Suspended:</label>
```

How can I do this using cakePHP FormHelper, and not resorting to manually entering the label HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible:

```
echo $this->Form->label('Account Suspended', null, array('for' => false));
```

Don't forget to use translation :P Almost every part of every code is reusable. If you don't need it now, you maybe spare some time in other projects ;)

Greetings
func0der

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't using `null` as the second parameter and it wasn't working.

Comment: No problem. Sometimes it helps to have a look in the source files of cakephp. You can see how things are working out and find features faster than in the documentation. Sometimes you'll find features that are not completly documented or missing features.
That's the biggest advantage of programming languages like PHP or Javascript. You can always have a look at the original code ;)

Answer (score 0):

What wouldn't you enter plain HTML ? If you don't need the autogenerated `for` attribute, there is no need to call the FormHelper I think.

```
echo '<label>Account Suspended:</label>';
$this->Form->input('account_suspended', array(
    'type' => 'checkbox',
    'label' => 'Prevent the user from logging in'
));
```

or

```
<label>Account Suspended:</label>
<?php
$this->Form->input('account_suspended', array(
    'type' => 'checkbox',
    'label' => 'Prevent the user from logging in'
));
```

would be perfectly valid

Comment: I know, I am just wondering how you can do it with the FormHelper.  It's weird that providing a `for` attribute, the option doesn't get merged with the default options array in the helper.

Comment: Using form function is mandatory if you have (or will have at some point in the future) a plugin to decorate your label, like some Bootstrap integration plugins.